# Multiple types of segues still do not work to move view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I recently upgraded to iOS 9 beta / Xcode 7, and one segue just stopped working. I have tried many different things, including completely deleting the view, and class file, and re creating both. For whatever, it gets to the point of the segue, and then it just does not complete that line. I have no idea what to do.

I have tried the regular

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToRules", sender: self)
```

as well as

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let rulesInViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RulesInViewController") as! RulesInViewController

self.presentViewController(rulesInViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

as well as

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RulesInViewController") as! RulesInViewController

self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

and none of them work. It is becoming very frustrating, and I just don't know what to do anymore. Is there anything that I could be doing wrong? I completely re did the view controller, and it still doesn't work. ALSO, it is an extremely basic view. All it has is one button, a logo, and a text view of rules for the app... The only code within that class is in the viewDidLoad, and it is defining the rules text.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem. When I right click on the View that contains the segue it shows "Triggered Segues" at the top, but my segue is not showing up, even though I can clearly see that it's part of that view. Deleting and re-adding the segue doesn't fix it.

Comment: I ended up re creating all the view controllers involved, and building and running after adding each element to the view. It was a horribly inefficient fix, but it then ended up working. What I found that when I added one textview, with code in the view controller for the text, it wasn't working, so I  added the text in the actual story board and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, check the identity inspector tab of your 'RulesInViewController' scene. It should have your custom class 'RulesInViewController' and module should have current -

Comment: So, in Segue Class, it should say "RulesInViewController" and Segue Module it should say "Current -" ? Because it won't let me input those.